# Derivative via the chain rule?

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Let $G$ be a Lie group; let $\alpha^X,\alpha^Y:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow G$ be a differentiable curves with $\alpha^X(0)=\alpha^Y(0)=e$ and let
\begin{equation*}
a(s,t):=\alpha^X(s)\cdot\alpha^Y(t)\cdot\alpha^X(-s).
\end{equation*}Let $\varphi:G\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be differentiable.

How can I prove that
\begin{equation*}
\frac{\partial^2}{\partial s\partial t}\bigg|_0\varphi(a(s,t))=\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \sigma\partial t}\bigg|_0\varphi(\alpha^X(\sigma)\cdot\alpha^Y(t))-\frac{\partial^2}{\partial \tau\partial t}\bigg|_0\varphi(\alpha^Y(t)\cdot\alpha^X(\tau))
\end{equation*}
using the chain rule for the composition $\varphi(a(s,t))=g(h(s,t))$ where
\begin{align*}
h:\mathbb{R}^2&\rightarrow\mathbb{R}^3\\
(s,t)&\mapsto(s,t,-s)
\end{align*}and
\begin{align*}
g:\mathbb{R}^3&\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\\
(\sigma,t,\tau)&\mapsto\varphi(\alpha^X(\sigma)\cdot\alpha^Y(t)\cdot\alpha^X(\tau))?
\end{align*}

If you are interested in the details about the context see Bröckner and Dieck's *Representations of compact Lie groups*, page 19.

Thank you!

Comment: In your first defn of $a$ do you mean them middle term to be $\alpha^Y$?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your correction!